# Easiest way to store and access values in hidden field

Tags: javascript, save, hidden-field

I'm looking for the easiest way to accomplish the following:

I let people do an online javascript task and I want to store and access the values in the hidden fields (e.g. multiple-choice answers) as txt file. Now, I'm not at all expert in setting up a server.
Is there a way to have them send their hidden fields automatically (or on button press) to an email? (I thought of hosting the html simply via googledrive)

In other words, what is the simplest way to do this?

This would really bring my project miles further.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do this. The best you could get is a `mailto` link including some content in the mail, but that would only work for people using a mail client software. So no gmail or outlook.com. Basically, if you want to send and store data somewhere, you will need server-side code.

But maybe you could simply use a thrid party service (like surveymonkey or so) to collect the info ? I don't know what you're up to...